# Force a constexpr function to be compiled at compile time, even if calculation inside contains a non-const array, by making the returned obj constant?

Tags: c++, compilation, constexpr, compile-time-constant

I read about `constexpr` functions and when they do a compile time calculation. Now i am at a point, where i have to fill an array with new values, thus the array cannot be `const`.

From what i know, a `constexpr` function is definitely evaluated at compile time, when every value inside the function is `const` and used functions are `constexpr` which also only use `const` values. Furthermore, an other post stated, that it's possible to force a compile time compilation by making the returned obj `const`.

Lets say, my function is a `constexpr`, but has a `non-const` array inside, but the returned object will be `const`. Will my function `calculation` be evaluated at compile time(forced?).

```
template<int Size, typename T>
struct Array{
    T array[Size];
    Array(const T * a){
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            array[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
};

template<typename T, int size>
class Example{

private:
    Array<size, T> _array;
    public:
        constexpr explicit Example(T * arr):_array(arr){};
        constexpr explicit Example(const T * arr):_array(arr){};
};

template<typename D, int size, typename ...buf, typename T>
constexpr auto calculations(const T & myObj){
    D test1[2];
    // calculation fills arr
    return Example<D, size>(test1);
}

int main(){
    const int size = 2;
    const double test1[size] = {1,2};
    const auto obj1 = Example<double, size>(test1); //compile time
    //obj2 calculations during compile time or run-time?
    const auto obj2 = calculations<double, size>(obj1);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot *force* a `constexpr` function to be evaluated at compile time. Deferring to run-time is always a valid option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what i know, a constexpr function is definitely evaluated at compile time, when every value inside the function is const and used functions are constexpr which also only use const values. Furthermore, an other post stated, that it's possible to force a compile time compilation by making the returned obj const.

All of these statements are wrong. See below.

---

No, a call to a `constexpr` function is only guaranteed to be evaluated at compile-time if it is called in a context *requiring* a (compile-time) constant expression. The initializer of `obj2` is not such a context, even if it is `const`.

You can force the initializer to be compile-time evaluated by declaring `obj2` as `constexpr`. (Which however has very different meaning than `const`!)

Even then it is not going to work, because `calculations<double, size>(obj1)` is not actually a constant expression. `obj1` is not a compile-time constant without declaring it `constexpr` as well. Similarly this doesn't work because `test1` is not a constant expression without declaring it `constexpr` as well.

Then you also need to make the constructor of `Array` `constexpr` and you need to actually fill the values of `test1` inside `calculations`, because accessing uninitialized values causes undefined behavior and undefined behavior makes expressions not constant expressions.

So all in all:

```
template<int Size, typename T>
struct Array{
    T array[Size];
    constexpr Array(const T * a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            array[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
};

template<typename T, int size>
class Example{

private:
    Array<size, T> _array;
    public:
        constexpr explicit Example(T * arr):_array(arr){};
        constexpr explicit Example(const T * arr):_array(arr){};
};

template<typename D, int size, typename ...buf, typename T>
constexpr auto calculations(const T & myObj){
    D test1[2];
    test1[0] = 0;
    test1[1] = 1;
    // calculation fills arr
    return Example<D, size>(test1);
}

int main(){
    const int size = 2;
    constexpr double test1[size] = {1,2};
    constexpr auto obj1 = Example<double, size>(test1); //compile time
    //obj2 calculations during compile time or run-time?
    constexpr auto obj2 = calculations<double, size>(obj1);
}
```

In C++20 there will be an alternative keyword `consteval` which one can use instead of `constexpr` on a function to force it to *always* be evaluated at compile-time. Currently there is no way to do that without making e.g. the destination of the return value a `constexpr` variable.

In fact your original code has undefined behavior. Because `Array` does not have a `constexpr` constructor, objects of that type can never be constructed in constant expressions. And because `Example` uses that type, it cannot be used in constant expressions either. This makes it illegal to put `constexpr` on its constructor, because a function declared `constexpr` causes undefined behavior if there isn't at least one valid set of template arguments and function arguments that would produce a constant expression. (The same then applies to `calculations` as well, because it uses `Example`.

So you *must* put `constexpr` on the constructor of `Array` in any case if your program is supposed to be well-formed.

Whether variables created *inside* the constant expression (e.g. inside `calculations`) are `const` does not matter at all.

Comment: I thanks you very much for the detailed explanation. Now i have a bigger picture of the `constexpr` and how i have to use it. It is also very interesting that variables created inside the constant expression doesn't have to be `const`, as long as the objects are in a context that, as you said, requires a compile time calculation.

Comment: @M.Mac A big point of confusion usually is the difference between `constexpr` and "*constant expression*". These are two different, but related concepts. `constexpr` on a function only means that it *can be sometimes* evaluated at compile time. And once a compile-time evaluation has started, you can do whatever you want in it, with exceptions. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) for a list of things you can *not* do in a constant expression. Even so a constant expression does only *need* to be evaluated at compile-time in a context *requiring* it.

Comment: so basically, if you obey the rules of a "Core constant expression" by not evaluating any of the given points at cppreference, you can calculate anything. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

from Microsoft:

> A constexpr function is one whose return value can be computed at
>   compile time when consuming code requires it. Consuming code requires
>   the return value at compile time, for example, to initialize a
>   constexpr variable or provide a non-type template argument. When its
>   arguments are constexpr values, a constexpr function produces a
>   compile-time constant. When called with non-constexpr arguments, or
>   when its value isn't required at compile time, it produces a value at
>   run time like a regular function. (This dual behavior saves you from
>   having to write constexpr and non-constexpr versions of the same
>   function.)

so your calculate function will evaluated compile time if all parameters are constexpr

Comment: "*or when its value isn't required at compile time, it produces a value at run time like a regular function*": That is saying that it will *not* be evaluated at compile-time in OP's case, because a compile-time constant is not required to initialize the variable. Even so, I assume that usually MSVC will do the calculation at compile-time if it can. In OP's case the evaluation can *never* be done at compile-time though, because they are not satisfying the `constexpr` requirements. Finally, even all that aside, Microsoft's documentation does not explain behavior of other compilers.

Comment: he declared obj2 as const and should be initialized by the return of calculate function this requires its value to be present at compile time especially it is declared as constexpr so the compiler will try to eval it compile time and will find a value.thats what I think.

Comment: No a `const` variable does not require its initializer value to be known at compile time. A `constexpr` variable does, though. See my answer. As I further explained in my answer OP's code can never be evaluated as constant expression (as-if rule aside). And even if, in this case it is the compiler's decision whether to evaluate at compile- or runtime. Nothing is forcing the former.